# Distribute nodes of different sizes without overlaps in Node Editor (Python)

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I'm trying to write a function for my script that will distribute the standard 5 nodes along the x axis, without overlapping.

My current setup looks like this:

```py
for index, node in enumerate((texCoord, mapping, texture, diffuse, output)):
node.location.x = 200.0 * index
```

This works well, and will separate the nodes equally at 200 px apart, which is fine normally but the mapping node is a little over-sized, and it covers my image texture.

Like so:
[image: nodes distributed but overlaping]

edit:
I have tried an if statement, that looked like:

```
for index, node in enumerate((texCoord, mapping, texture, diffuse, output)):
if node == mapping:
    node.location.x = 400.0 * index
else:
    node.location.x = 200.0 * index
```

but that does this:
[image]

I also tried adjusting the values, like so:

```
for index, node in enumerate((texCoord, mapping, texture, diffuse, output)):
if node == mapping:
    node.location.x = 100.0 * index
else:
    node.location.x = 250.0 * index
```

But that ends up not moving the texture coordinate enough:
[image]

I also tried using a while loop, but that crashes blender.

I feel like there is probably a better way to adjust for this size, but I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because nodes are not necessarily in the order we want in the node tree, I made a list of the nodes in their proper order (listing them from left to right). I then loop through that list and get the nodes by name in the node tree, moving them accordingly.

```
import bpy

nodes = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes
list = ['Texture Coordinate', 'Mapping', 'Checker Texture','Diffuse BSDF', 'Material Output']
loc = 0
for i in list:
    nodes[i].location.x = loc
    loc += nodes[i].width + 50
    nodes[i].location.y = 0
```

The script is rather simple. I loop through my list of node names; then simply set the node's x location to the `loc` variable.
The next line `loc += nodes[i].width + 50` is adding the width of the node, plus 50 (the margin around the nodes) to the already tallied widths.
Then next time around the next node will get moved over that amount.

The only important part is that you add the width of the node to the `loc` variable *after* the node has been moved.

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that the area around the node was a measured attribute. That is awesome.

Comment: When you access the nodes using node_tree.nodes, it returns the name of each node inside the material as a string? If not, how is the connection between the string name and the node itself established?

Comment: Yep you are right I am storing the nodes' name in my list. `node_tree.nodes['Mapping']` is one way to get to the mapping node. However if it was the second mapping node I added to the tree, its name by default would be "Mapping.001"

Comment: Thats really neat. Lets say we do need 2 mapping nodes, just for the sake of the argument. How might you change that to be more flexible? Or would you just go and hardcode the name "Mapping.001" instead of "Mapping" into a secondary list?

Comment: I actually am running into an issue where I need to sort the image nodes. separately from the rest. If I were to do that, is there a way to sort the shaders inside of the material by type, and create a list like that?

Comment: @Rug well kind of. It would be easy to loop through the nodes and get all "TEX_IMAGE" (`node[].type`) but then what? Ask yourself: how do you want to sort them? alphabetically wont help any, so you will need some metric, maybe the [node connections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5471/2217) to get something useful to sort on.

Comment: An excellent approach at node arrangement with python can be found on the following page under the heading Arranging Nodes: https://medium.com/@behreajj/coding-blender-materials-with-nodes-python-66d950c0bc02 AFAIK most of the code there is valid for 2.8 too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to space it out far enough, I have increased the pixel difference for both the regular index as well as the mapping node. This is my code now:

```py
for index, node in enumerate((texCoord, mapping, texture, diffuse, output)):
if node == mapping:
    node.location.x = 200.0 * index
else:
    node.location.x = 300.0 * index
```

I still feel like there must be a more elegant solution, but I will leave this answer for those in the meantime.