# How to create a script that will evenly distribute selected nodes?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, customization

I would like to create a script that would evenly distribute the locations of some selected nodes so that I can better organize my node trees. I'm seeking a script solution for this issue, instead of using Node Wrangler, because Node Wrangler functionality is not available in Animation Nodes.

I imagine script would function something like:

1. X = C.active_nodes
2. For nodes in X find locations of *left_most_node_location* and *right_most_node_location*
3. Set location of nodes to distance between *left_most_node_location* and *right_most_node_location* divided by the length of X

I'm not very good with Python, so I'm not really sure how I would write this for Blender.

[image]

Comment: Don't think you really need that. You can press: `S + Y + 0` to align the nodes vertically. Also *Node Wrangler* comes with an *Align Nodes* button...

Comment: @brockmann yes I know you can scale to align them but I would like to distribute their locations evenly

Comment: Enable *Node Wrangler* (you'll need it anyway) and *Align Nodes* does what you want...

Comment: @brockmann I'm seeking a script solution to this problem because I want to use the script in Animation Nodes, which is not compatible with Node Wrangler

Comment: Aha... you should add that to your post @ANimator120.

Comment: I created [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88833/30030) to answer a similar question, this might help you